# Pepper robot: subscribeCamera's name argument

Tags: pepper

I want to capture an image from the camera of Pepper, so first I subscribe to a camera using `subscribeCamera` method. I have seen the [documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/vision/alvideodevice-api.html#ALVideoDeviceProxy::subscribeCamera__ssCR.iCR.iCR.iCR.iCR).

So the function needs some parameters:

```
 std::string ALVideoDeviceProxy::subscribeCamera(
     const std::string& Name,
     const int& CameraIndex,
     const int& Resolution,
     const int& ColorSpace,
     const int& Fps)
```

> Parameters:
>
> - Name – Name of the subscribing module.
> - CameraIndex – Index of the camera in the video system (see Camera Indexes).
> - Resolution – Resolution requested (see Supported resolutions).
> - ColorSpace – Colorspace requested (see Supported colorspaces).
> - Fps – Fps (frames per second) requested to the video source (see Supported framerates).

My question is about the first parameter: **name**, because the documentation says:

> **Warning**
>
> The same Name could be used only six time.

Why the name can be used only 6 times? after the six times the function stops to return a value. So I have to change the name every 6 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point is more something like "you couldn't use more than 6 times, without unsusbscribing first".

The subscribe process return you a name to refer to. 
If this name exists already it will give you another one.
like:
subscribe( "toto") => toto
subscribe( "toto") => toto_2
subscribe( "toto") => toto_3
...
But only 6 times (lazy programmer, but not only, you should have a design problem in this case, eg: forget to unsubscribe).

So I think the "normal way" is to unsubscribe, and then it should do that:
subscribe( "toto") => "toto"
unsubscribe( "toto") ( "toto" is not used anymore, so the system can use it later)
subscribe( "toto") => "toto"